# Jira Custom UI App Stalling on requestJira Invocation - Possible Permission Issues

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, forge, custom-ui

I’ve recently experienced a fatal issue that prevents me from publishing/testing any new Jira Custom UI applications. This issue persists across all the projects I deploy. Even sample code doesn’t deploy correctly.

I’m able to create/register my app without any problems, and I’ve double-checked my manifest for potential errors. I can deploy and install the app into Jira Cloud successfully. However, when I try to access the app, it stalls whenever requestJira is invoked. There’s no console error; the app simply becomes unresponsive. Through debugging, I was able to confirm that the requestJira function is where it stalls.

I suspect the error might be related to permissions. When running forge install, I receive the following warning:
“The scopes or egress URLs in the manifest are different from the scopes in your most recent deployment to development. Try running forge deploy -e development before installing.”
However, redeploying doesn’t resolve this warning. Also, forge lint shows no errors. Another odd thing is that while the app isn’t listed as a connected app, it does appear in the list of installed apps.

Any assistance with this would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers!